# Fragment navigate back without adding to back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

This was asked in one of the interviews. The scenario is described as follows :

MainActivity (initially has Fragment A added to it.). On pressing a button, it goes to Fragment B, *without adding A* to backstack. On pressing a button in Fragment B, it adds 'B' to back stack, and goes to Fragment C. Now, in fragment C, I have a button through which I directly want to navigate to fragment A (which wasn't added to back stack). Is there any way possible to do this?

Comment: @Nitesh Didn't get the solution for this particular scenario, but when A is added to backstack, it's easy to navigate back using this method : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStackImmediate